# Method that inserts an object in any point in the array in java

Tags: java, arrays, object

Without the use of any array lists or vectors or any other type of built in java data structure besides arrays, I need to write a method that inserts an animal object in any position and shifts what ever is in the current position and others to the right.

While doing this I must ensure that the collection hasn't already reached its max value.

How do I actually write this method out?  My version won't compile do to errors. I cannot figure out this problem.  Can someone please help me write this method using my current code and provide an explanation?

```
private  Animal [] objects;
final int MAX_ANIMALS = 100;

public AnimalObject()
{
    objects = new AnimalObject[MAX_ANIMALS];
}

public AnimalObject(Animal[]a)
{
    objects = a;    
}


public void addAnimal(Animal a,int position)
{ 
    Animal [] newAnimal = new Animal[objects.length];
    for(int i =0; i < position; i++)
    {
        newAnimal[i] = objects[i];
    }
    newAnimal[position] = a;
    System.arraycopy(objects, position, newAnimal, position+1, objects.length - position);

    for(int i = position+1; i < newData.length; i++)
    {           
        newAnimal[i] = objects[i-1];    
    }
```

Comment: What is your compiler error?  Can you add that to your question please.

Comment: If it won't compile ***due*** [N.B.] to errors, what are the errors?

Comment: I reformatted your code to align everything and unless you're leaving some things  out it doesn't make any sense, which is probably why it isn't compiling.  For one your first constructor is calling itself, and then declaring an array of itself, both of which you cannot do.  I think you may want to do some research on how to write your own class and how to declare & initialize arrays.

Comment: Please post at leas a full code of your class. In posted sample 'addAnimal' method is not cloded. What is the 'newData'  variable? It is not declared in your code sample

Comment: didn't go through your code but [this link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/Insertsthespecifiedelementatthespecifiedpositioninthearray.htm) may be useful, take a look at it

Comment: You could consider having your method return a new array that has a length of your current one + 1. Just feed the new value in the index given and everything will get pushed over.

Answer (score 0):

I will not attempt to fix your incomplete code, I will however offer a possible solution and a piece of advice. Let's start with the advice: do not reinvent the wheel. Unless you are doing this as an excercise, do use an `ArrayList`. It is made precisely to do that. If it is an excercise, I am not sure if you will gain much by looking for answers on StackOverflow. Best examine `ArrayList` source code :)

As for a possible solution, here is one - I have tried to mimic what you have pasted above (with minor naming tweaks for readability):

```
public class AnimalsArray {

    final int MAX_ANIMALS = 100;
    private Animal[] animals;

    public AnimalsArray()
    {
        this.animals = new Animal[MAX_ANIMALS];
    }

    public AnimalsArray(Animal[]a)
    {
        this.animals = a;
    }

    public void addAnimal(Animal animal, int position) {
        Animal[] newAnimals = new Animal[animals.length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < position; i++) {
            newAnimals[i] = animals[i];
        }
        newAnimals[position] = animal;
        System.arraycopy(animals, position, newAnimals, position + 1, animals.length - position);
        this.animals = newAnimals;
    }
}
```

You will obviously want to add more methods to that (like retrieval of array's elements I guess). However keep in mind that the above code is **HIGHLY** inefficient. The array grows **each time** when an element is added!

When you want to do this right, you should:

1. Have an initial size of array be larger than required (empty constructor does create a maximum capacity array, but "fixed" version of your code does ignore that and allocate a new array every time an element is added anyway).
2. When array grows (i.e. you add an element and the array is not large enough to add a new one) you should calculate how much it should grow - an algorithm for that should be designed. When it grows you could use Arrays.copyOf method to allocate a larger array

You can get more ideas on how things should be done by examining ArrayList. Apart from being more efficient it is also generic and this cannot be said about your code (this could be fixed but again - use ArrayList!).